# Quarkus. Registering CDI Beans classes from a third party library

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm using quarkus to implement a rest-api defined in a 3rd party library.
This library contains providers that implement ParamConverterProvider, ExceptionMapper, ConstraintValidator, a default implementation of resource interfaces, and so on. The library is missing beans.xml and jandex index.

Problem: It is required to selectively initialize some of the classes present in the library. Please advise how this can be done.

What I tried:

1. Initialization of all beans of the quarkus.index-dependency property library. The method is not suitable, because there are many providers in the library that do not require.
2. These and the following methods do not work:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        register(UnsupportedOperationExceptionMapper.class);
    }
```

3. 

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyResteasyBootstrap extends ResteasyBootstrap {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        super.contextInitialized(event);
        ResteasyProviderFactory factory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
        factory.registerProvider(UnexpectedErrorExceptionMapper.class);
    }
```

4. 

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ResteasyProviderFactory> {
    private ResteasyProviderFactory factory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
    @PostConstruct
    void initialize() {
        factory.registerProvider(UnsupportedOperationExceptionMapper.class);
    }
    @Override
    public ResteasyProviderFactory getContext(Class type) {
        return factory;
    }
```

5. 

```
@QuarkusMain
public class MyQuarkusApplication {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        ResteasyProviderFactory factory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
        factory.registerProvider(UnsupportedOperationExceptionMapper.class);
        Quarkus.run(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [ticket](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23643) on gihub, in which they suggested 2 options for solving the problem, both were useful for different situations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).